# How to get status message for a python file in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have `python` script that I am using in `Pysaprk`. In this script I am creating a table in `hive` using `data frame`. The `Python` file is like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

# df can be any dataframe that has columns Id and test_time.
df = "I have as a result of querying a different table"

hivedb='MySql'
table='abc_123'

# Register the Data Frame as a TempTable
df.registerTempTable('mytempTable')

#Time:
date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#Find min value ID:
min_id = sqlContext.sql("select nvl(min(id),0) as minval from mytempTable").collect()[0].asDict()['minval']

#Find max value Test_time:
max_test_time = sqlContext.sql("select max(test_time) as maxtempo from mytempTable").collect()[0].asDict()['maxtest_time']
max_test_time = str(max_test_time)

# Create Table in Hive using the temptable
sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` stored as parquet as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))

#insert values to tracking table in hive
sqlContext.sql("insert into table testing.tracking select '{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}'".format(hivedb,table,min_id,max_test_time,date,status))

sc.stop()
```

In the below statement if the `create table statement` fails then the status should be `fail`, or else `success`

```
sqlContext.sql("insert into table testing.tracking select '{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}'".format(hivedb,table,min_id,max_test_time,date,status))
```

How to get the status of the `create table statement` to get used in a insert statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of an failure, an exception is thrown by the `sqlContext.sql` call. this exception can be caught and the right status can be set.

```
status = 'success'
try:
  sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}` stored as parquet as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
except:
   status = 'fail'
```